# Flipping an array of planes in random order using Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to make an array of planes to flip one at a time in random order. So far I managed to flip them one at a time in order. Below is an image of my 3D viewport and Animation Nodes setup. How could I proceed?

[image: Viewport and Nodes]

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What do you want for final animation?

Comment: I am trying to flip the tiles 180 to reveal the white on the other side one tile at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar effect made by shuffling Matrix list:
[image]
[image]

Another method by providing random offsets:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Falloff you could use Compose Matrix. Math Nodes are there just to make a single plane rotate and you can feed it 100 random numbers to make them all rotate. Clamp node is there to restrict rotation.

[image: Nodes]

[image: Result]

### One at a time

To make the planes rotate one at a time you need to replace the random numbers with a list of integers (One step is the time it takes for one rotation) and suffle them.

[image: Nodes]

[image: Result2]

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. Now to add one texture to all tiles

Comment: quick follow up, is it possible to get one tile to rotate at a time? Thanks